# F# Returning a Boolean

Tags: f#

First shot at [Euler #3](http://projecteuler.net/problem=3) in F#, and I would like to return a boolean more elegantly than this mutable value.

```
// A number is prime if can only divide by itself and 1.  Can only be odd.
let isPrime x =
    if (x%2L = 0L) then
        false
    else
        let mutable result = true
        for i in 3L..x/2L do
            if (x%i = 0L) then
                result <- false
        result

let a = isPrime(17L)

// True
printfn "%b" a
```

The L's are as I'm forcing the function to return bigints (there has to be a better way too, but 1 step at a time)....

**Edit**
Gradbot's solution

```
let isPrime x =
    // A prime number can't be even
    if (x%2L = 0L) then
        false
    else
        // Check for divisors (other than 1 and itself) up to half the value of the number eg for 15 will check up to 7
        let maxI = x / 2L

        let rec notDivisible i =
            // If we're reached more than the value to check then we are prime
            if i > maxI then
                true
            // Found a divisor so false
            elif x % i = 0L then
                false
            // Add 2 to the 'loop' and call again
            else
                notDivisible (i + 2L)

        // Start at 3
        notDivisible 3L
```

Comment: Gradbot - I liked your answer.. but then it has been deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can replace the else clause with a forall:

```
Seq.forall (fun i -> x % i <> 0L) { 3L .. x/2L }
```

and then further reduce it to a single expression:

```
x % 2L <> 0L && Seq.forall (fun i -> x % i <> 0L) { 3L .. x/2L }
```

although I see no reason for treating 2 differently, you can simply do:

```
let isPrime x = 
    { 2L .. x/2L } |> Seq.forall (fun i -> x % i <> 0L)
```

Comment: One potential benefit of handling 2 separately - you can iterate by twos (`3L .. 2L .. x/2L`) in the second step, which is a touch faster.

Comment: I meant taking into account the rest of the code. Algorithmically there's still a lot of ways to improve on that